# How can I display book details in Laravel using Eloquent join and where clauses?

Tags: sql, laravel, database, eloquent, crud

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$title

```
public function show(string $id) { 
    $books = DB::table("book_tbls")
        ->where("author_tbls.id", "=", $id)
        ->where("author_tbls.id", "=", "book_tbls . author_id")
        ->where("categories.id", "=", $id)
        ->where("categories.id", "=", "book_tbls . category_id");   
    
    // $books = book_tbl::find($id);
    return view('books.show', compact('books'));
}
```

I am learning laravel for 3 months, Now I am writing library system. In show function, I will show the details of the books eg. author name, book title and category but when I join those tables the properties are not shown. Please help.

Comment: fyi, you're using the Query Builder, not Eloquent. And you're not using joins

Comment: You would need to `->get()` your result(s) first

Comment: When I use ->get(), this "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'next-library.categories_tbl' doesn't exist" error shown

Comment: I don't think so, there's no `categories_tbl` in the code you posted (was your comment meant for the answer below?)

Comment: fyi, `$id` is supposed to be the `id` of the _book_ you're trying to get. I doubt that the author and the category have the same `id` as the book you're looking for. (`->where("author_tbls.id", "=", $id)` and `->where("categories.id", "=", $id)` make no sense)

Answer (score -2):

joins are missing. here i am adding the joins

public function show(string $id) {
$books = DB::table("book_tbls")

1. List item

   ```
    ->join("author_tbls", "book_tbl.author_id", "author_tbl.id")
    ->join("categories_tbl", "book_tbl.category_id", "categories.id")
   ->where("author_tbls.id", "=", $id)
   ->where("categories.id", "=", $id)
   ```

   // $books = book_tbl::find($id);
   return view('books.show', compact('books'));
   }

Here I assume in book_tbl we have column name author_id. author_id column referencing to author id exists in author_tbl. same for the categories

Comment: I've tried your code but the "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::$title" error is still showing

Comment: That still wouldn't _get_ any results

Comment: where is the get method ?. try this
 
  $books = DB::table("book_tbls")
        ->where("author_tbls.id", "=", $id)
        ->where("author_tbls.id", "=", "book_tbls . author_id")
        ->where("categories.id", "=", $id)
        ->where("categories.id", "=", "book_tbls . category_id")
        ->get();

Comment: I got it, it works.